# Which is correct? Its or Their

Tags: single-word-requests

Which is correct? The Gardening Club holds its event on Monday or The Gardening Club holds their even on Monday?

Answer (score -1):

The correct one should be "its", because here, the club is being referred to in a singular context, i.e., one unit, and so "its" is probably the answer.